Isomorphism between motivic cohomology and algebraic cobordism
Let $MGL$ be the algebraic cobordism defined by Voevodsky, and $\Omega$ the algebraic cobordism constructed by Levine and Morel. For motivic cohomology $H^{p,q}$, we use Suslin-Voevodsky's definition. In their book "algebraic cobordism", Levine and Morel showed (Theorem 1.2.19) isomorphisms between Chow groups and algebraic cobordism groups
$$CH^*(X)\simeq\Omega^*(X)\otimes_{\mathbb L}\mathbb Z$$
where $\mathbb L$ is the Lazard ring.
It is known that $H^{2*,*}(X)=CH^*(X)$. Recall that Levine had showed that $MGL^{2*,*}(X)\simeq\Omega^*(X)$ over a field of characteristic zero. So we have isomorphisms
$$H^{2*,*}(X)\simeq MGL^{2*,*}(X)\otimes_{\mathbb L}\mathbb Z$$
over field of characteristic zero.
My question is whether we have such isomorphisms over arbitrary fields. E.g. field of positive characteristic.
